# Forms - Cycling Through Records

Tags: ms-access-2010, searchbar

I have a MS Access 2010 database with two tables; one for Contracts and the other for Projects. Relation is 1 Contract to many projects. I have a MainForm (Single) that pulls up the contract with a subform that shows related projects (located in Detail section of MainForm) . I WAS able to search through each record of the MainForm using the record navigator at the bottom. As the Contract record changed on the MainForm the subForm was populated with the projects for next Contract record. Estimated number of records (Contracts) was about 65

Today I added two new fields both in the Contracts table and Projects table to capture the date last modified (LastModDate & LastModTime). Everthing is populating as expected except now the search record bar for the MainForm is showing 227 records which is the total number of project records. The search bar for the the SubForm displays the number of projects for that Contract record.

Looking for advice on pulling the search next record back to the contract level versus the project level.

Comment: See whether the Record Source for MainForm has changed.  If it's a query, use its SQL in a new Access query in the designer and find out how many rows it returns there.  And hopefully you will see what you need to change so it returns only the rows you expect.

Comment: You should also check your Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields properties on the subform control, to see how the subform relates to the main form.

Comment: @HansUp I checked the Record Source for the MainForm and it is a query. When I run the query it returnes 152 records (unique contracts).

Comment: @HK1 I checked the Link Master Fields and Link Child Field properties for the table feeding the main form and the table feeding the subform. I'm having difficulty finding where to check the link between the sub and the main form though. My record source for the subform is a query of the projects table and the link between the projects and contract is a field in the projects table called getPrimeContract.

Comment: @HK1 disregard comment above, could not edit; The Link Master Field is 'ContractID' which is the primary key for the table storing the contract information. The Child Field is 'getPrimeContract' which is a lookup to pull in the ContractID. I created the subform my dragging the 'qryProjects' onto my Main Form 'frmContracts'

Comment: So I figured out the problem. Somehow the Record Source on the main form changed to Select an innerjoin where the ContractID matched the getPrimeContract on the subform query. somehow this caused the number of records showing in the record navigator to be 227. When I reset the Record Source of the main form back to tblContracts it now reads 67 records which is correct. thank you for the help everyone